# How to subscribe to document changes in all SharePoint sites

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

What is the best way to perform an operation every time a document is uploaded or updated on a SharePoint site library when I have 100,000 sites?

I know how to subscribe to changes for the documents of one library (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0)). Do I need to create 100,000 subscriptions, one per site library?

Is there a limit to the number of active subscriptions?

Is there a way to create tenant wide subscriptions?

Comment: I can think off the following (1) Webhooks/Subscription/Notifications (2) Microsoft Graph Data connect - give a try and see if it suits your scenario.

Comment: Does it helped you?

Comment: @Dev I haven't tried yet... but subscribing to the notification for file changes requires calls to `/drives/{id}/root`, which means I need one subscription per site, hence my question: can I create 100,000 subscriptions?